# Determine limit of indeterminate form.

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, infinity

If the question is $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^x+1)^{\frac1x}$$ Do you just say that because $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x$ is $0$, the original function has limit approaching 1, without caring the $e^x$?

Comment: No. [Alpha says e](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+to+infinity+%28e^x%2B1%29^%281%2Fx%29).

Answer (score 2):

Write:
$$
(e^x+1)^{1/x}=(e^x)^{1/x} (1+e^{-x})^{1/x}=e\times (1+e^{-x})^{1/x}
$$
which goes to $e$ as $x \to \infty$

Answer (score 2):

Apply the squeeze theorem:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^x)^{\frac1x}\leq \lim_{x\to\infty}(e^x+1)^{\frac1x}\leq \lim_{x\to\infty}(e^x\cdot e)^{\frac1x}$$